# How do I get a character above \gets?

Tags: arrows

I want something like `\xleftarrow{\text{x}}`, but with `\gets`. The problem is that `\xleftarrow`extends to the length of the text. But i want arrows with the same length. Is there a possibility?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: The problem is that `\xleftarrow`extend to the length of the text. But i want arrows with the same length.

Comment: Where is the macro `\gets` from?

Comment: Is `\overset{\text{x}}{\gets}` what you are out after?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You can use `\gets` also at `listings`.

Comment: @Mico You have switched `\leftarrow` and `\rightarrow` in your above comment.

Comment: @hooy - Thanks for catching this mistake! I'll delete the earlier comments as they are just too misleading.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - @hooy has pointed out that I'd made a mistake in my earlier comment. What I *should* have written is that `\gets` is a shortcut for `\leftarrow`, just as `\to` is a shortcut for `\rightarrow`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use either `\stackrel` or `\overset` (provided by the `amsmath` package) to achieve your typesetting needs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\overset" macro
\begin{document}
$a\overset{\mathrm{x}}{\gets}b$, 
$a\stackrel{\mathrm{x}}{\gets}b$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
\overset{\text{x}}{\gets}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
 $a \buildrel \rm x\over\leftarrow b$
```